# Streaming video from PiCamera to Windows using Java and Python

Tags: python, java, raspberry-pi

I'm making a robot with Raspberry. My goal is:

1. Code a server on Rasbperry using Python that captures the image from camera and sends data via socket
2. Code a client on PC using Java that reads data from socket and show it in a JavaSwing window

So I can see in real time what the Raspberry Camera see.

I tried this code for my project and I get the same latency.
My python code is:

```
import socket
from time import sleep
import picamera

ADDRESS = '192.168.1.XXX'  # My Address - SERVER
PORT = 2000        # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)

server = socket.socket()  
server.bind((ADDRESS, PORT))
server.listen(0)   

connection, addr = server.accept() # Accept one connection
params = (1280, 720, 48, 25000000)
client = connection.makefile('wb') 

print('Connected to', addr)

camera = picamera.PiCamera()
camera.rotation = 180
camera.resolution = ( int(params[0]), int(params[1]) )
camera.framerate = int(params[2]) #48

try:
camera.start_recording(client, format='h264', intra_period=0, quality=0, 
                   bitrate=int(params[3]) )
    print("Recording started...")
    camera.wait_recording(60)

finally:
    camera.stop_recording()
    print("Recording stopped...")
    client.close()
    server.close()
    camera.stop_preview()
    print("Connection closed")
```

My Java code is the next:

```
private final int WIDTH = 1280,  HEIGHT = 720;
private final int FPS = 48;
private final int BITRATE = 25000000;

public InputStream connect(String address, int port) throws IOException {   
    socket = new Socket( InetAddress.getByName(address), port )     
    return socket.getInputStream();
}

public void openWindow(VideoPane video) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(video);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT) );
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

public void avvia() throws IOException {

    VideoPane video = new VideoPane(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    openWindow(video);
    InputStream in = connect(serverAddress, serverPort);
    streamToImageView( "h264", FPS, BITRATE*2, "ultrafast", 0, in, video);

    try {
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace(); }

}


public void streamToImageView( final String format, final double frameRate, final int bitrate,
                             final String preset, final int numBuffers, InputStream input, VideoPane video) {
        try{
            final FrameGrabber grabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber( input );
            final Java2DFrameConverter converter = new Java2DFrameConverter();
            grabber.setFrameRate(frameRate);
            grabber.setFormat(format);
            grabber.setVideoBitrate(bitrate);
            grabber.setVideoOption("preset", preset);
            grabber.setNumBuffers(numBuffers);  
            grabber.setMaxDelay(10);
            grabber.start();

            Frame frame;
            BufferedImage bufferedImage;

            while (!stop) {
                 frame = grabber.grab();

                if (frame != null) {
                    bufferedImage = converter.convert(frame);
                    if (bufferedImage != null) {
                        video.updateFrame(bufferedImage);                 
                    }
                }//if frame
            }//while
            grabber.close();
        }//try
        catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }//streamToImageView

public class VideoPane extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage currentFrame;

    public VideoPane(int width, int height) {
        this.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(width,  height) );
        Timer timer = new Timer(FPS, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                repaint();             
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    public void updateFrame(BufferedImage frame) {
        this.currentFrame = frame;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (currentFrame != null) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            int x = (getWidth() - currentFrame.getWidth()) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - currentFrame.getHeight()) / 2;
            g2d.drawImage(currentFrame, x, y, this);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }//paintComponent
}//VideoPane
```

I notice that the RPiCamera library code the stream video to h264 before sending to socket. I think that latency maybe is due to this computational overhead. 
I'd like to try another conversion format but I'm unable to decode the stream when received.
I also tried to use UDP protocol but FFmpegFrameGrabber needs a InputStream and the UDP can only provide the ByteStream ofreceived packet.
The other possible problem maybe a connection delay, so I tryed to connect raspberry with Ethernet. This video show the latency when raspberry is connected via Ethernet to router and PC via Wireless:
[LatencyVideo](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1gTHuADfncll_rlY0a5zC0ikxEax00_JG?usp=sharing)

Have you some ideas for reducing this latency?
Thanks

Comment: Related: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/163042/31562